# commande line for compress repository one by one

Tags: bash, zip

I'm looking for a commande line to compress only repository in zip archive. But one repository = one zip archive

exemple :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
.
./von_Thunen
./bestiole
./iznogoud
./irius
./epiSim
./resilience
./micMac
./christaller
./sisbio
./proiePredateur
```

And I would like

```
ls 
.
./von_Thunen.zip
./bestiole.zip
./iznogoud.zip
./irius.zip
./epiSim.zip
./resilience.zip
./micMac.zip
./christaller.zip
./sisbio.zip
./proiePredateur.zip
```

thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find * -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec zip -r {}.zip {} \;
```